# Initial render is slow for >500 components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a list of up to 2k list components that need to be rendered (each an expandable component) and change the data in them on the fly.
There's no slow speed in terms of changing on the fly. Updated data is quick and only those components that have new data are re-rendering, so there's apparently no unnecessary re-renders going on. But it's the initial load of the page that has the components on there that's slow. It takes about 3-4 seconds, then they all appear.

I've covered as many posts as I can, but they're all about unnecessary re-renders, which is not my issue. I'm using Redux to manage the store, and that data is what determines how many of these components to create and render.

Is it just that rendering that many items takes time, and it's actually functioning just fine, considering that any change or update to the data inside these components is not causing a complete re-render?

I did run a test where I added timestamps to all of the processes and console logged when each event happens - it takes 3ms to calculate the 2k components, but then 3-4 seconds before the all display.

**update**
It appears as though this is not a react issue, but a browser issue, in that React isn't updating the dom (and so re-rendering everything all the time), but the DOM is struggling with 500+ components changing on the canvas.
Any thoughts on how to better handle this many objects slowing the browser/canvas render?

Comment: maybe better to add more details? e.g. what component library you are using? is there any async task? for example, this one looks ok https://codesandbox.io/s/great-blackburn-36qn5

Comment: @alvinsj That example only renders cheap components. What if his involve expensive calculations?

Comment: might be, or maybe complicated DOM tree

Comment: Thanks @alvinsj, The component is material UI's ExpansionPanel. Each item in the list needs its own panel which is populated with the information in the list, but also needs to have interactive buttons attached. The information in the list is updated at 1Hz asynchronously and is connected to a redux store. At the moment, the issue is in having so many things rendered, the calc time is small, but the render time is huge. I did try react-window, but it still took a long time to load them all. I'll try your example above and report back.

Comment: Update - it appears linked to buttons. When I use ~500 ExpansionPanels, it's ok, even with data sourced from the list (async grabbed from the server). No issues appear until I add buttons to the panels. But why does it matter if all 500 of the panels are closed so the buttons are effectively hidden and not shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but it is a solution.
Turns out the `ExpansionPanel` component from Material-UI has a not well highlighted inbuilt property called `TransitionProps`, which can be set like `TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: true }}`. This will mean that the complex stuff in the expanded portion isn't calculated until it needs to be expanded and is dismopunted from the DOM when you close it.

Comment: I also ended up using react-virtuoso - a much simpler tool, and combined that with a calculation on the Redux side to always supply the list items to render. Much better now... almost professional-like... almost

Comment: Holy cow. I was rendering around 60 `Collapse` components. Without `unmountOnExit`, the initial render took about 1000ms. With `unmountOnExit`, the initial render was reduce to 300ms. surprised-pikachu.jpg

Comment: Yeah. I tried rendering thousands of rows of plain old boring 'row' data with basic html buttons and found no issues whatsoever. Add the 'pretty' collapse... still ok (albeit a tiny bit slow)... then add buttons to the collapse... wow - instantly terrible. I think this is the issue in using really pretty components with lots of animated things - like the buttons with their fancy interaction when clicked or hovered. But I did end up using `react-virtuoso` and then doing all the background work to determine what does/doesn't go in the list to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [virtualising](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or [windowing](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). Basically how it works is that you only load what's on the screen at a particular point of time during the lifetime of your application, and when scrolling happens, you monitor what's going in and out of the viewport, manipulate them accordingly. Check out both packages and see which one suits you better. They cover pretty much all the common use cases :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those.

Comment: @Fonty Glad to help!

Comment: react-window didn't work so nicely. Firstly, I'm not a fan of the fact that it creates its own container with its own scrollbar, but I can live with that. But as the components are themselves dynamic with animation, it lead to strange animation of things. When scrolling down the list, I needed to wait some time before those components became clickable. I also have a collapsible legend at the top, which toggles awfully now. The ideal is a progressive loader for a one off load. i.e. when you first head to the page, it loads 5, then the next 5 until the end of the data.